# compiling esp32 app with eclipse on windows 7: "make" not found

Tags: windows, makefile, compilation, eclipse-cdt, esp32

I'm trying to setup my first development for esp32 with eclipse on windows 7.

I installed esp-idf using esp-idf-tools-setup.exe installer which should install
everything needed.

I'm testing with the hello world example app from esp-idf. I can compile it using the python command line

```
idf.py build
```

But I need eclipse, it's a bit less obvious... I followed [these](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/get-started/eclipse-setup-windows.html) instructions:

- In this page, I can see that there's a need of msys. So I installed
  msys2 64 bits.
- I copied the xtensa-esp32-elf dir into the "msys64\var\opt" directory to match the PATH variable (and updated it based on the documentation)

Now, when compiling with eclipse, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/program/esp-idf/tools/windows/eclipse_make.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/program/esp-idf/tools/windows/eclipse_make.py", line 29, in main
    make = subprocess.Popen(["make"] + sys.argv[1:] + ["BATCH_BUILD=1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

Python make is unable to launch "make". The thing is I can't find a make exe anywhere...

[This](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/get-started/eclipse-setup.html#eclipse-install-steps) other page states that I must run

```
make menuconfig
```

before building with eclipse but, of course, this does not work better for the same reason...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did add mys2 thinking it will contain everything needed.

In fact msys2 is delivered with a very minimal set of features. I had to install make using the msys2 package manager with the following command:

```
pacman -S make
```

Pretty simple when you know!

Comment: haha, well - there are a lot of options! - I would think that gnuwin32 or mingw32 are probably the simpler ones and cygwin is probably the most involved (there is a huge list of packages to choose to install including loads of compiler tool chains etc....)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in windows you have `nmake` (IIRC installed with visual studio tools - or the free where vstools compiler pack). Or you can install something more like gnu-make from one of:

- mingw32 : [link](http://www.mingw.org/)
- cygwin : [link](https://www.cygwin.com/)
- msys2 : [link](https://www.msys2.org/)
- gnuwin32 : [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

There are others as well. Some of these have `make` command (if you add the bin folder to your path) others will have things like `mingw32-make` which you may have to alias (I made a batch file called `make.bat` which just calls `mingw32-make %*`. But where ever you install `make` (and `nmake` IMHO is a really limited poor version of make) you need to add it to your windows path before you run your python script. So in short I think you are just missing a set of tools...

Another option is to just copy `...\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe` to `...\MinGW\bin\make.exe`

Answer (score 0):

For esp-idf cmake projects, try this https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin